# Display Column name instead of ID using inner join in SQL Server

Tags: sql

Q. i need to display data using select statement in sql having a inner join for worktype=code 
But i want to display Code_Name in Column [Worktype ] 
for a SSRS report

worktype varchar,
code_name varchar
[table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHrAj.jpg)

[table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9ccU.jpg)

Comment: dont'post image only  .. post the table schema as  text too..

Comment: Leave the inner join as it is. Add the column you want after select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly this might help:

```
SELECT table2.SR_No
      ,Work_Type = table1.Code_Name
      ,table2.Transaction_Type
      ,table2.Date
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.Code = Table2.Work_Type
```

This will return the Work_Type column to display the Code_Name column from table1.